# Plotting with gWidgetstcltk

Tags: r, graphics, plot, gwidgets

I've made a gui with a button, the handler of which executes a plot method of a class I made, it uses ggplot2 and grid/gridExtra in a normal R session to put together the plot. It works fine using the plot() function in console. My button/handler is below:

```
Plotbutton <- gbutton("Plot!", container=MainWindow,
                  handler=function(h,...){
                    plot(analysis, linesplot=svalue(linecheck), lineplot.legend=svalue(linelegcheck), baseannotate=svalue(bpcheck), bpfreq=as.numeric(svalue(bpspin)), mosaic.bars=svalue(mosaiccheck), mosaic.scale=as.numeric(svalue(mosaicspin)), combine.plots=svalue(combinecheck), condense.mosaics=svalue(condensecheck), labfontsize=as.numeric(svalue(fontspin1)), legfontsize=as.numeric(svalue(fontspin2)))
                  })
```

I'm not sure of the reason, but loading gWidgets, gWidgetstcltk, and the package required for my plot method, and then clicking the button, nothing is plotted to the R graphics environment, however in RStudio the plot panel is not updated until the GUI is exited. The graphic does appear in a window in the normal Windows RGui though.

Can anyone suggest why this is happening?

Comment: I'd guess you need to print(...) the call. Might also be related to event handling with tcltk and RStudio, but let's hope that isn't the case.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it works from the R-console and not from a function is that the R-console will invoke `print()` automatically if nothing else is stated.  Within a function R does not do this, so if you want to print a graph, you must explicitly state `print(graph)`. Try

```
print(plot(analysis, linesplot=svalue(linecheck), lineplot.legend=svalue(linelegcheck), baseannotate=svalue(bpcheck), bpfreq=as.numeric(svalue(bpspin)), mosaic.bars=svalue(mosaiccheck), mosaic.scale=as.numeric(svalue(mosaicspin)), combine.plots=svalue(combinecheck), condense.mosaics=svalue(condensecheck), labfontsize=as.numeric(svalue(fontspin1)), legfontsize=as.numeric(svalue(fontspin2)))
```